# what does mean striped and notstriped shared library?

Tags: linux, shared-libraries

when i send library and binary to the device,which library(striped/notstriped) to used ? And also how to set environment variable to be permanent in ubuntu(bash shell) ?

Comment: It depends on what device, and how does it use the shared library. If the shared library is a plugin, it should not be stripped.

Comment: Device is arm9 based architecture, i want to put one shared library. But i donot know which library(striped/notstriped) to used.Actually i donot know difference between these two library ?

Answer (score 2):

You mean "stripped", not "striped". Stripping means removing extra information that's needed for debugging, such as symbol tables that tell the debugger where variables and internal functions are located. So if you use a stripped shared library and try to debug it using gdb, you won't get much useful information if you examine a stack frame belonging to a library function.

To make an environment variable permanent, put it into your `.profile` for terminal sessions, and `.xinitrc` for GUI sessions.